# Load Page in Background on Link Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Problem:**

When I click on a link, it opens the destination page immediately and it shows the images of the destination page loading. It looks unappealing.

**Desired result:**

When I click a link, I want to stay on the CURRENT page for a couple seconds (while the destination page loads in the background), then show this page after the images have all loaded.

Should I create a div with a negative z-index and load it in the background? Are there any pre-made functions for this?

Comment: Are you talking about images slowing down the rest of the page load? If so look into lazy loading for image heavy sites.

Comment: You may try `Link Prefetching` (but take care of browser compatibility) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_prefetching

Comment: I'll have one large image at the top of the destination page that will be loaded. I can see it loading as soon as I go to the link. Therefore, I don't think lazy loading would help. If I can stay on the current page after the link click for 1-2 seconds, then show the destination, that would be great! :)